# RabbitMQ missed heartbeats when in Docker background

Tags: python, docker, rabbitmq, pika

I have implemented rabbitmq for long running tasks. I have implemented concurrent.features to multithread and keep the heartbeats alive. And this works if I run it interactively/myself.

What I am trying to accomplish is:
1. Spin up VM
2. VM downloads latest docker
3. Docker acts as a consumer for a rabbitMQ queue
4. When docker consumes message, acknowledge, and die (docker and instance)

Now if I run the docker interactively, and consume the message, heartbeats are alive and all works as normal.

However, when I automate this process on the VM. I get missed heartbeats. Which is quite confusing since if it is working interactively, why doesn't it work when the process is automated?

This is the error I get:

```
2019-11-07 14:14:28.904 [warning] <0.14199.0> closing AMQP connection <0.14199.0> (<some-ip>:58064 -> <some-ip>:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'user'):
client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
```

Possibly the TCP port gets closed after a while if not run interactively?

Also, when I add `--privileged` it 'sometimes' works. Without privileged is simply does not work. But with it, it works sometimes. Super confusing!

Any suggestions are welcome. I'm not too sure why this does what it does.